# Windows CE 6.0 sql server requires encription on error

Tags: sql-server, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6

We have created an application on Windows CE 6.0 that when tries to connect to our SQL server gets an error. "SQL Server requires encryption ON."

Sadly we dont have access to configuration part of server but we suspect it is using forced encryption.

When we try to access it trough SQL management studio there are no problems.

Does anyone knows how to make our app connect to that SQL server without changing anything on the server.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Code? Connection string? Try adding "Trusted_Connection=yes;Encrypt=yes;" to your connection string.

Comment: When i add Encrypt=Yes, the app gives an error, "unknown connection option in connection string: encrypt"

Comment: This is my conn string Data Source=***.***.***.***,50381;Initial Catalog=********;User ID=*******;Password=*******